# VBA access insert query does not return an error

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access database and i have a field attributed with unique indexed values. The problem is that when i execute an SQL insert statement with a duplicate value it does not raise an error it rather just skips the statement as if an `On Error Resume Next` statement is present above it.

Here is the gist of my code `CurrentDb.Exceute "Insert Into IS24 (geocodes, realestateId) values (123456, 7788339)"`
So if 7788339 is already present it will simply not do the insert but would not raise an error either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "Insert Into IS24 (geocodes, realestateId) values (123456, 7788339)", dbFailOnError
```